# is there SQL injection?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have this kind of code with statement query, could you help me is there SQL injection or it is a secure code?

```
<%


  String aUser = request.getParameter("user");
  Conn aPlug = null;
  Statement aStatement = null;
  ResultSet aResultSet = null;

    aPlug = Conn.getPlug("fetchAssetId");
    aStatement = Conn.getConnection().createStatement();
    aResultSet = aStatement.executeQuery("select pass, file_name from users where user_id = owner and user_name = '" + aUser + "'");


    %>
```

thank you

Comment: Very definitely injection there :)

Comment: Use a `PreparedStatement` and don't put that code into a JSP page.

Comment: Doing string concatenation and directly executing it can always lead to SQL injection. Look into `PreparedStatements`.

Comment: Well, first of all, this particular code throws a `NullPointerException` long before SQL injection becomes a problem. But yes, after you fix the NPE it becomes vulnerable to injection attacks.

Comment: And why even reason about it? Just use prepared statements with bind parameters.

Comment: This is pretty much the canonical textbook example for SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Yes, this code is vulnerable.

Injection happens when you allow user provided values directly into your query. Here's the user provided value:

`String aUser = request.getParameter("user");`

It's coming from a GET parameter, i.e. `?user='; DROP TABLE..`

And here's the bit where it's used in your query:

`user_name = '" + aUser + "'`

You should instead use a [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), as described quite nicely on [bobby-tables](https://bobby-tables.com/java).